# referring to an installed pod within Prefix.pch

Tags: ios, cocoapods, pch

Finally taking on pods. Everything seems to work, for example, dropped in Parse, install pod'd, see it in a view controller.m file just fine.

BUT.. now i want to drop Parse into the pch as i use it so often. My pre-pods line was:

```
#import "Parse/Parse.h"
```

I tried this, and

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

and

```
#import <Parse.h>
```

.. and every variant i can think of, no luck. I can of course drop imports where required, but this is more convenient, despite the suggestions not to use this route.

What i find most confusing is that the UI pre-fills in the path for me for second option, so it finds it, but on build, it fails with

'Parse/Parse.h' file not found.

Thanks for suggesting a working syntax.

Comment: I thought this would elicit a quick reply. I am sure it is easy, i am just missing something. The import works in regular .h/.m's but not the pch file. This just feels so strange. 

I am ready to shelve the idea and just follow suggested protocols and drop imports for everything needed into each file as required, but for something line app constants and for parse, this is just so repetitive.

Comment: This surely has a simple answer. After carefully creating a new single-view app, using the same podfile, and step-by-step dropping in incremental actions leading up to the podfile install.. 

..i am at a point where a pod-installed repo is importing properly, and tested, build success. 

.. then pulling out the import and dropping it into the pch results, not in any errors in the related .m file, but a "file not found" in the pch. With the EXACT same import line. I am clearly missing something about the requirements for the pch, which already houses UIKit and Foundation properly.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the perfect answer, as there are so my cocoapods fans using the repo that this is likely due to my newness to it, but i had to manually create an entry into User Header Search Paths which was "Pods" and set it recursive.

Then all was good.